# How do I get my Android Studio project to build after pulling it from a git repo?

Tags: android, parse-platform, gradle

I have a working, compiling Android Studio project that I want to backup with Git.  Uploading it is no problem, but the cloned project refuses to compile.  It gives the error,

```
  "Cannot get property 'compileSdkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist"
```

I began this project from the blank Parse.com project.  Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.parse.starter"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'

}

/* Uncomment if you enable ProGuard and you want to automatically upload symbols on build.
parse {
  applicationId "YOUR_APPLICATION_ID"
  masterKey "YOUR_MASTER_KEY"

  // Make symbol upload automatic. Otherwise, use e.g. ../gradlew parseUploadSymbolsDebug;
  uploadSymbols true
}
*/
```

The first line of the "android" section above is where the error comes from.  Android Studio tells me that .ext of rootProject does not exist.  What have I done wrong here?

Edit: When I open build.gradle from the file explorer, I get ext is undefined.  When I open the project root and from there open build.gradle, every single variable is undefined.

Here is my build.gradle file (the build.gradle that is in AndroidStudioProjects, the directory holding all of my projects)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 22
    buildToolsVersion = "22"

    minSdkVersion = 11
    targetSdkVersion = 22
}
```

Settings.gradle at root

```
include ':parsestarterproject'
```

It had been

```
include ':ParseStarterProject'
```

New error after changing settings:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':parsestarterproject'.
>
> > Could not find property 'com' on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=null, targetSdkVersion=null,
> >     renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null,
> >     renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=null, versionName=null,
> >     applicationId=null, testApplicationId=null,
> >     testInstrumentationRunner=null, testHandleProfiling=null,
> >     testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null,
> >     mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[],
> >     mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}}

It referes to the "com" in the applicationID.
.

Comment: It may help you. [Github link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseUI-Android/issues/8)

Comment: Can you show the root build.gradle file? The problem is more likely in this file.

Comment: Do you mean the build.gradle within AndroidStudioProjects?

Comment: how is your settings.gradle?

Comment: The original project was called ParseStarterProject.  After modifying settings.gradle, I get the new error shown above.

Comment: I guess the problem is there, it's not seeinf "ext" on the parent

Comment: I added the new error.

Comment: @Shine, that was pretty clearly the problem, but I'm asking how to fix it.